# Got BSOD error on Windows 8 during logging in

Tags: windows-8, bsod

I installed Windows 8 and I was working with it 3 hours ago...
I shut it down, and after a while I turned it on again, but the huge difference is that is I can’t log in anymore, I got `BSOD` and this error:

***`your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We’re just collecting some error info, and then we'll restart for you.`***

When I got this error I tried to solve it by using some options that Windows 8 gives me, but unfortunately they didn’t work.
I installed the new Windows but the problem wasn’t solved.
What should I do?

Comment: What are the "options that Windows 8 [gave you]" that you used? Also, when did the BSOD occur, before the login screen, or after you tried to login?

Comment: umm, options such as automatic repair and restore PC or reset it,these are what i meant

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\Minidump to the desktop, zip it, upload it to your SkyDrive, dropbox or other service you sue and add a link here so that we can look at the Dumps with Windbg.

Comment: @mohammad amin.MR have you uploaded the dumps?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Run Win8 in safe mode ([here's how](http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/))
2. Run `msconfig` > `Services` tab > Check `Hide Microsoft services` > Turn all off
3. `Startup` tab > Turn all off
4. Reboot

If that helps, run msconfig again and try turning on services and startups one-by-one (reboot after each one). This way you should be able to check what's causing the problem and get rid of this.

Also you may want to check logs under the safe mode to see what's the problem.